# Java - what data structure gives fastest performance for pre-loading string array and checking if string exists there?

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I have a list of country codes like us, fra, uk, etc.

I need to preload them and check to see if a string exists there. What is the fastest performing data structure that I can use since comparing strings can be resource intensive?

Should I make a static array of strings or an ArrayList or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: There are only like what, 200-some country codes? A linear search would likely be a fine O(n). A binary search would be better O(lg n), with an initial sort. And a map would be O(1), for a space trade-off .. *if it even matters*. Use the 97/3 rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of short strings and want to test whether a given string is among them, you might want to use a `HashSet<String>`, which provides extremely fast lookups and can answer your queries very quickly.  For example:

```
Set<String> myStrings = new HashSet<String>();
myStrings.add("us");
myStrings.add("fra");
/* ... */
if (myStrings.contains("test-string")) {
   // String is there.
} else {
   // Nope!  String is not there.
}
```

If you have a large set of much longer strings, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be an appropriate (but slightly less space-efficient) data structure.  If you know in advance what strings you are working with and that set never changes, consider looking into the [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAWG) data structure.  Neither of these are part of the Java standard libraries, though a quick Google search should turn up information about both.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, just one more question.  If it is in a file where I keep consts, should I make the HashSet a "public static final" - I am not too sure if that is the right practice.

Comment: @Genadinik- That totally depends on the context, though I would strongly advise against making something like this a public field.  I would instead build a method that queries the `HashSet` so that if you need to change the implementation later on, code using the `HashSet` doesn't break.  It also prevents other pieces of code from accidentally breaking the `HashSet`.

Comment: good point. Thank you :)